# Can I say: "Used to drink everyday, but now I've finished" (as "done with it")

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

So that's pretty much my question.
It's needed for a rhyme.
I know it sounds better and makes more sense with "im done..", but I was just trying to fit the word "finished" in there for a rhyme scheme.
In case I can't use "finished" I'll just go with "done with it", even though it's going be a lot harder to rhyme my other words ;)

Thank You!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with finished, even if it's not as common. It would be understood in context.

Comment: It's unidiomatic, which is hard to distance from 'it sounds unnatural'. 'I've quit' is the most idiomatic informal version.

Comment: "but now I'm done with it" works too

Comment: Also common in U.S. English are "...but now I've given it up" and "...but now I'm on the wagon." These have the advantage over "...but now I've finished" that it can't be misread as suggesting that you've simply drunk the entire contents of the bottle and now are finished with it because it's empty.

Comment: It's OK in a poem, but maybe would not be used as such in speech.

Comment: Now I’m done with that.  Now I’m through with that.  Now I’m finished with that.

Comment: "Now I no longer do it" or "I don't do it anymore" or "I stopped". "I've finished" means you were doing a continuous activity like cooking a particular thing, and you stopped that one instance.

Comment: Sometimes you're just stuck.  I'm currently stymied by "Airbnb".

Comment: It's sort of unidiomatic because *finished* implies that you had a task of a particular size and then you completed it.   "I set out to read *War and Peace* and now I've finished."

Comment: Is it possible that "Now it's finished" might work?

Comment: "I used to drink every day but now the wine cellar is empty." - that's the sort of connotation I get from this. Compare "I used to work on my novel every day but now I've finished (or it's finished.)"

Comment: "...but that's all finished".

Comment: Did you really want to write *everyday*, rather than *every day*?

Comment: It's almost a play of words, with finished meaning both stopped and drank to the bottom. Whether a play of words is acceptable is up to the poet.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are doing it for the rhyme sake but it still sounds artificial. Maybe you can play around with it and say something along these lines: but now these days are gone or but now I am not the same)))

Answer (score -2):

You could use the word "diminished" if the poem doesn't require future abstinence? If it does then "relinquished" might work.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/diminished

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/relinquished